# Setter Property Injection don't work in static class, using ASP.NET MVC 5 and Structuremap

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, structuremap

I create a static class Util in the library project for purpose define common method in project asp.net mvc 5, i use structuremap.mvc5, but it don't initialize the Install of IService is static property, i declare in static class. Thank you for helping:

Config Class Ioc:

```
public static class IoC {
    public static IContainer Initialize() {
        ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
        {
            //Standard registration
            x.For<IStudentRepository>().Use<StudentRepository>();
            x.For<IStudentService>().Use<StudentService>();
            x.For<IApplicationSettings>().Use<WebConfigApplicationSettings>();
            x.For<IAuthProvider>().Use<FormsAuthProvider>();
            //Setter injection
            x.Policies.FillAllPropertiesOfType<IStudentService>().Use<StudentService>();
            x.Policies.SetAllProperties(prop =>
            {
                prop.OfType<IStudentService>();
            });

        });            
        return ObjectFactory.Container;            
    }
}
```

Class Util:

```
public static class Util 
{       
    private static IStudentService _studentService;

    public static IQueryable<User> GetAllStudents()
    {
        return _studentService.GetAllStudents();
    }

    public static T ParseEnum<T>(string value)
    {
        return (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), value, true);
    }

    public static List<PermissionType> GetAllPermissionByUserID(int userID)
    {
        return _studentService.GetAllPermissionByUserID(userID);
    }

    public static bool IsAuthentication(string user, string password)
    {
        return _studentService.IsAuthentication(user,password);
    }
    public static User FindUserByUsername(string username)
    {
        return _studentService.FindUserByUsername(username);
    }
}
```

Error Page:
[image]

Comment: why you setting class Util is static?

Comment: @Linh Tuan: Because i call class Util anywhere in solution and don't initialize object from class.

Comment: this problem "_studentService" is uninitialized

Comment: you can create contractor for "_studentService" in util class

Comment: Yes, Do you have any ideal for the issue ?

Comment: @Linh Tuan: i can resolve it by create constructor, but i see other developer using structuremap(inject property) for resolve this issue.

Comment: Yes, this solution i don't work on server, i often using it in Unitest Project same: public static IWindsorContainer _container; public static void BootstrapContainer()
        {
            _container = new WindsorContainer().Install(new DaoFactoryInstaller(),
                                                        new ServicesInstaller());
        }
var repos = _container.Resolve<ITimeZoneRepository>();

Answer (score 1):

You wasn't initialize _studentService, so you have to do it.
for create new instance of studentService you can use ServiceLocator or Property Setter

Try this:

```
public static Util 
{
     _studentService=ObjectFactory.Container.GetInstance<StudentService>();
}
```

and for Setter Injection you use this:

```
 [SetterProperty]
 public IStudentService StudentService{get;set;}
```

but I'm not sure about setter property in static class.